# Local Notification always open the MaterialApp home Screen when closed

Tags: flutter

I am implementing `flutter_local_notifications` and scenarios where user is still inside the app and exits the app by simple pressing home button work fine, user can still go to the desired screen from an notification, but when the user exits by pressing back button (android) clicking the notifications sends user to the home defined screen.

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:local_demo/notification_manager.dart';
import 'package:local_demo/screen1.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await NotificationsManager().initializeNotifications();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      navigatorKey: NotificationsManager.navigatorKey,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Screen1(),
    );
  }
}
```

notifications_manager.dart

```
import 'dart:developer';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:local_demo/screen2.dart';

class NotificationsManager {
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
  static final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey =
      GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  Future<void> initializeNotifications() async {
    AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        const AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_launcher');

    const IOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
        IOSInitializationSettings();

    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
            android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
            iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
    log('NotificationsManager.dart::: notification!!!');
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
  }

  shootNotification(String title, String body, String payload, context) async {
    // var flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
    //     HealthCareApp.getNotificationsPlugin(context);

    var androidNotificationDetails = const AndroidNotificationDetails(
      '001',
      'data',
      category: 'information',
      importance: Importance.high,
    );
    var iOSNotificationDetails = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var generalNotificationDetails = NotificationDetails(
        android: androidNotificationDetails, iOS: iOSNotificationDetails);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .show(002, title, body, generalNotificationDetails, payload: payload);
  }

  showNotification(String? payload) {
    navigatorKey.currentState!
        .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Screen2(payload!)));
  }

  void onSelectNotification(String? payload) async {
    log('main.dart::: notification arrived!!!');

    if (payload != null) {
      log('notification payload: $payload');
    }

    // print('payloadReference: $payload');
    // BuildContext _context = navigatorKey.currentContext;

    showNotification(payload!);
  }
}
```

screen1.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:local_demo/notification_manager.dart';

class Screen1 extends StatelessWidget {
  const Screen1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Screen1')),
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            NotificationsManager()
                .shootNotification('title', 'body', 'pay111', context);
          },
          child: const Text('Shoot Notification'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

screen2.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Screen2 extends StatelessWidget {
  String notificationContent;

  Screen2(this.notificationContent, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Screen2')),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(notificationContent),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace push with pushNamed  and set RouteSetting
In MyApp Widget replace Screen1 at home with variable init it with Screen1 like this var route ='Screen1'
home=route
variable route should be global variable so you can edit it so put it in sparete file you can access it from everywhere
then on shownotification edit it route ='screen2'

```
 App.navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed(
      route,
    );
```

Comment: I made the changes and still having the same issue. Would you mind give a more clear example, for instance I had to put the 'screen1' as a widget since home only accept widget, as follows

`home: route,
      routes: {
        screen1: (context) => Screen1(),
        screen2: (context) => Screen2()
      },`
`showNotification(String? payload) {
    route = Screen2();
    navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(screen2, arguments: payload!);
  }`
a new file:
`Widget route = Screen1();

const String screen1 = 'screen1';
const String screen2 = 'screen2';`

Comment: Hi, Sorry there was mistake in my solution just replace 'home' with 'initialRoute', it should be named route

Comment: Read more in named route in https://medium.flutterdevs.com/navigate-with-named-routes-in-flutter-5de44922789e